# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException in java by sending an invitation link by official email in java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

when is send link on website through email then I got an error  Error sending mail Exception is :: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.
If you have any idea please comment.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Provide more details including code, log stacktrace etc. Also, if you are using a Gmail account to send emails, you will need to do some additional steps for setting up authentication and allowing the mails to be sent from the account. Example: https://mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: I had a similar issue, did your code worked in the past and suddently stopped ?